# MySQl return records that match AND/OR against second table values

Tags: mysql, sql

This is such a basic question but for some reason all my knowledge of SQL has just exit the building. Three basic tables:

```
Table A
id | name
---------
1 | John
2 | Mike
3 | Henry
4 | Cooper

Table B
id | tag
---------
1 | chocolate
2 | ice cream
3 | cookies
```

and a table which joins the two:

```
Table C
id | name_id | tag_id
---------------------
1 | 1 | 2
2 | 1 | 3
3 | 2 | 1
4 | 3 | 2
5 | 3 | 3
```

I want to find the people who like BOTH chocolate and cookies. The following gives me all the people that like chocolate and cookies, but I only want the people who like both (chocolate AND cookies instead of chocolate OR cookies).

```
SELECT name FROM tablea a JOIN tablec c ON a.id = c.name_id WHERE c.tag_id IN (1,3)
```

The following obviously doesn't work:

```
SELECT name FROM tablea a JOIN tablec c ON a.id = c.name_id WHERE c.tag_id = 1 AND c.tag_id = 3 GROUP BY name
```

but it's essentially what I want. Also, I'd like to do this without involving the tableb in the JOIN, because where I'm using this there will be various other tables joined in and I don't want to confuse the picture. This has got to be so simple!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One hackish method:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(c.tag_id) AS cnt
FROM tablea a
JOIN tablec c ON a.id = c.name_id
WHERE c.tag_id IN (1,3)
GROUP BY name
HAVING cnt = 2
```

Count up how many preferences each user has (which would be limited to chocolate or cookies via the where clause), and then return only those users which have 2 preferences.

Comment: So long as `Table C` can't have duplicate records (ie unique constraint on `(name_id, tag_id)`), this looks great

Comment: @Phill: I guess some people could REALLY like cookies, but at least in mysql you can also have `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` to handle the dupes case.

Comment: Does `GROUP BY name_id` change the results?

Comment: I would recommend grouping by a.id and selecting a.id and a.name, since a duplicate a.name would otherwise lead to unexpected results.

Comment: @sll: it would if there's more than two of the same name in the db. for the OP's sample data, no difference. but in practical terms, grouping on the primary key field would be preferable. (Unless you want to do some bogus stats like "all johns like cookies+icecream while freds only like cookies".

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and **fastest** way is to join the `tablec` twice, one for chocolates and the other for cookies

```
select name 
  from tablea a
 inner join tablec chocolates on a.id = chocolates.name_id
 inner join tablec cookies    on a.id = cookies.name_id
 where chocolates.tag_id = 1
   and cookies.tag_id = 3
```

Comment: @Phil thanks for pointing out the duplicated rows. I have edited to `select distinct`. `Group by name` would also do the trick

Comment: Well I rollback my last comment, as this query does not return duplicated rows, thus no need for distinct clause